# (Android) Fragment onCreate not running whole method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on an android project, where I fetch data from a JSON dump. I have a fragment, where i call an Asynctask from another public Java Class. For some reason won't my fragment run it's whole onCreateView, and after I call the Asynctask, then it stops running the rest of the onCreateView. There's an important for loop, which won't run.

The fragment looks like this, and you can see in my comments where it stops running.

```
public class DataTabelFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView sensor1;

jsonAsynctask jsonasynctask = new jsonAsynctask();


public DataTabelFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_data_tabel, container, false );

    sensor1 = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.sensor1Box );

    new jsonAsynctask().execute(); //THIS IS THE LAST CODE RUNNING

    //NOT RUNNING CODE AFTER THIS

    System.out.println( jsonasynctask.allDevice );

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonasynctask.allId.size(); i++) {

        // String date_time = allDate_time.get( i );
        // String date = date_time.substring( 0, date_time.indexOf( "T" ) );
        // String time = date_time.substring( date_time.indexOf( "T" ) + 1, date_time.indexOf( "+" ) );
        // textView2.append( allId.get( i ) + "  " + allTemp.get( i ) + "  " + allHum.get( i ) + "  " + allBat.get( i ) + "  " + allMode.get( i ) + "  " + date + "  " + time + "  " + allLux.get( i ) + "\n\n" );
        sensor1.append( jsonasynctask.allId.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allDevice.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allTemp.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allHum.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allBat.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allMode.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allLux.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allDate_time.get( i ) + "\n\n" );

    }

    return view;

    }

}
```

This is the public java class where the Asynctask is:

```
public class jsonAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

JSONObject deviceArray;
JSONObject tempArray;
JSONObject humArray;
JSONObject batArray;
JSONObject modeArray;
JSONObject date_timeArray;
JSONObject luxArray;

JSONArray json2;

List<String> allId = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDevice = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allHum = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allBat = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allMode = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDate_time = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allLux = new ArrayList<String>();

String basicAuth;
String line;
String json_string;
String json;
String cxwebURL;
String credentials;
String password;
String username;

Gson gson;
ProgressDialog pd;
String data = "";
//HttpsURLConnection connection;
HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

String id = "";
JSONObject idArray;

URL url;


private static String encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData) {

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString( binaryData, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE );

}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        username = "xxx";

        password = "xxx";

        credentials = username + ":" + password;

        cxwebURL = "https://" + credentials + "@xxx.com/fetch.php?device=xxx";

        try {

            url = new URL( cxwebURL );

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            basicAuth = "Basic " + new String( encodeBase64URLSafeString( credentials.getBytes() ) );

            connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
            connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Language", "en-US" );
            connection.setUseCaches( false );
            connection.setDoInput( true );
            connection.setDoOutput( true );
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( stream ) );

            line = "";

            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            json2 = new JSONArray( data );

            for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
                idArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                deviceArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                tempArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                humArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                batArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                modeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                date_timeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                luxArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                id = idArray.getString( "id" );

                String temp = tempArray.getString( "temp" );
                String device = deviceArray.getString( "device" );

                String hum = humArray.getString( "hum" );

                String bat = batArray.getString( "bat" );

                String mode = modeArray.getString( "mode" );

                String date_time = date_timeArray.getString( "time" );

                String lux = luxArray.getString( "light" );

                allId.add( id );
                allDevice.add( device );
                allTemp.add( temp );
                allHum.add( hum );
                allBat.add( bat );
                allMode.add( mode );
                allDate_time.add( date_time );
                allLux.add( lux );


            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute( result );

        gson = new Gson();

        json = gson.toJson( data );

        json_string = data;


        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any error in your asynctask execution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It runs the whole Asynctask, but won't return to the onCreate method on the fragment. As I see it. By the way, thanks for using your time on this!

Answer (score 0):

If you have studied about AsyncTask it runs on background UI .

Although you are calling Loop after this method but Loop is on Main UI  so it executes before AsyncTask is completed.

so it feels like Loop is not executing

Put your Loop in onPost() method of AsynTask so it get executed once AsyncTask has completed its work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, i know about android lifecycle and asynctask, but i on purpose removed the loop from onPostExecute, as i need to use the asynctask on multiple fragments, and i don't want a nullpointerexception

Comment: You can do a hack.. Like send any boolean value to your asynctask and in onPost method check if that value is true execute your loop.